# Laravel Get value from form to date('request->date')

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I just tried using the pop-up form with Laravel.

I want to get a value in the "start" and "end" columns (on views) so that it can be retrieved by the controller.

This is a pop-up form that contains the "start" and "end" columns.

**Views**

```
<div class="modal fade col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="frmProducts" name="frmProducts" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label">Dari:</label>
                            <input type="date" name="start" class="form-control" value="yyyy-mm-dd">
                            <label class="col-form-label">Sampai:</label>
                            <input type="date" name="end" class="form-control" value="yyyy-mm-dd">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="{{ route('test') }}" id="export" class="btn btn-outline-success mb-3">PDF</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
----
$(document).on('click','.open_modal',function(){
        var url = "sub.domain.com/folder";
        $.get(url, function (reservasi) {
            console.log(reservasi);
            $('#start').val($request->start);
            $('#end').val($request->end);
            $('#export').val("test");
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }) 
    });
```

**Controller**

```
public function test(Request $request)
    {
        $start = date($request->start);
         $end = date($request->end);
        $reservasi = Reservasi::join('kamar','reservasi.idkamar','=','kamar.id')
        ->select('reservasi.id','kamar.name as kamar','reservasi.konfirmasi', 'reservasi.created_at')
        ->whereBetween('reservasi.created_at', [$start, $end])
        ->orderBy('reservasi.konfirmasi','ASC')
        ->get();
dd($reservasi);

    }
```

Edit: I intend to get the value from "start" and "end" column as a limit to what date we want to print.

We have successfully created the print script. But not with the date limit. For this reason, our Controller uses dd () to see the results of data retrieval. In the end we will replace this code with the printing code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put laravel code inside javascript or client code in general like that you have to use blade template:

```
$('#start').val({{$request->start}});
$('#end').val({{$request->end}});
```

But the code in general isn't clear try to elaborate a little bit because i cannot understand how you consume the $start and $end variables and look for them at the same. Eithere you get them from controller and you consume them in javascript or the otherway around.Can you justify more?

Comment: Sorry, my question is not clear.

I want to get the "start" and "end" values from views and can be captured by the controller.